# p:fileDownload primefaces 3.5 and Liferay 6.1 ga1, not supported mine type

Tags: primefaces, download, liferay, data-export

As subject title, when I try to export my data to a excel file then allow client user to download it.  My code throw not supported mine type application/vnd.ms-excel.

Try with p:dataExporter, fail.

Try with p:fileDownload, fail.

I had some search and realize that primefaces file download and data exporter do not support liferay portal, maybe it still impossible until ver 6.1 ga1 ?

Is there any alternative solutions here please :-?

ps: I copy code from primefaces demo pages.

Comment: I already have iText and apache-poi lib

Comment: This is a bug in primefaces. Please vote for primefaces issue [1109](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=1109) if you would like to see it resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is still possible, with the following workaround.

```
[Public StreamData getFile() {
  // 1. initialize the fileInputStream
  // 2. get Liferay's ServletResponse
  // 3. write the file into the outputStream
  // 4. return null to this method
}][1]
```

for more detail sample code, please refer 
http://kianworknotes.blogspot.com/2013/03/primefaces-filedownload-in-liferay.html#more

if you are using POI to generate the excel. 
in step 3, just write the following

```
workbook.write(outputstream)
```

Comment: I just attached liferay-faces-1513-patch-SNAPSHOT.jar to [FACES-1513](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/FACES-1513). This patch should make it possible to use p:fileDownload and p:dataExporter in a portlet without doing any portlet-specific coding in your own code.
But there are two limitations:

p:fileDownload – PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop) doesn’t call the “stop” function due to cookie issues in a portlet environment.

p:dataExporter – unable to get type=”xml” working but  “csv”, “pdf”, and “xls" worked fine.